# How to overlay image on a custom carousel?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a custom carousel from [here](https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/full-slider/).
I would like to overlay an image on the top left corner of the carousel.

I have searched all over but nothing works with my carousel because it always deforms it.

```
    <!-- Carousel -->
    <header>
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>
                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
                    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('images/c1.jpg')">
                      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
                        <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
                    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('images/c2.jpg')">
                      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
                        <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
                    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('images/c3.jpg')">
                      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
                        <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                      </a>
                  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                      </a>
                </div>
              </header>

    <div class="logo">
                    <img src="images/logo.png">
                </div>
```

```
    /* css */
    .carousel-item {
        height: 100vh;
        min-height: 350px;
        background: no-repeat center center scroll;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
      }

    #logo{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

The image simply goes under the carousel, instead of overlaying it.

[jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vhbtf6e/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logo is a class in your HTML code and in CSS it is selected as ID

so, the code will be:

```
.logo {
    .....
}
```

instead of

```
#logo {
    .....
}
```

Comment: I never though of this because in my other project it worked perfectly, but aparently carousels change that workflow. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

No parent element is positioned appropriately (relatively). Wrap the code in a container and position the container relatively, and then the div(child of the wrapper) with the image inside of it will act accordingly. Or, stick the div inside the header so the logo div is the child of the header.

Comment: I only put it outside so it would be easier to see where it was, instead of having to look for it inside de carousel. Since it didn't work anyways, it wouldn't make a diference.

Comment: The question as been answered already, but thank you anyways!